# why does IsSingleByte Encoding's GetByteCount do calculation

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding

I’ve inspected AsciiEncoding's GetByteCount method. It does long calculations rather then returning String.Length. It doesn’t completely make any sense to me. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: It *looks* like it is trying to account for high/low surrogate pairs... which seems odd for ASCII

Comment: @Marc: Accounting for surrogate pairs isn't too daft IMO, but it doesn't seem to work. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I've just tried reproducing this, and I can't currently force an ASCIIEncoding instead to have a different replacement. Instead, I'd have to use Encoding.GetEncoding to get a mutable one. So for ASCIIEncoding, I agree... but for other implementations where `IsSingleByte` returns true, you'd still have the potential problem below.

---

Consider trying to get the byte count of a string which *doesn't* just contain ASCII characters. The encoding has to take the `EncoderFallback` into account... which could do any number of things, including increasing the count by an indeterminate amount.

It *could* be optimized for the case where the encoder fallback is a "default" one which just replaces non-ASCII characters with "?" though.

---

Further edit: I've just tried to confuse this with a surrogate pair, hoping that it would be represented by a single question mark. Unfortunately not:

```
string text = "x\ud800\udc00y";
Console.WriteLine(text.Length); // Prints 4
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(text)); // Still prints 4!
```

Comment: EncoderFallback cant replace a single byte into 2 or more bytes. it would be something like converting Æ into AE but it never does such thing. it just converts ç into c for example. producing 2 byte representation for single char would break a lot of design. both editors and word processors. and if they have taken the encoder fallback into account, their code should have been other then currently what we have. same is true for GetCharCount

Comment: one more thing. i think default fallback for ascii isnt one that replaces non-ASCII characters with ? its the best match fallback which (dont know why) didnt make public. it produces for ç c, not ?

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest: An EncoderFallback *can* replace a single character with an entire string - e.g. `new EncoderReplacementFallback("ouch");`. As for the default replacement - the docs claim ". If you use the default encoder returned by the Encoding.ASCII property or the ASCIIEncoding constructor, characters outside that range are replaced with a question mark (?) before the encoding operation is performed." Perhaps that's inaccurate though...

Comment: I've just tried using Encoding.ASCII with a ç and it gave me a ?: `string text = "x\u00e7y"; byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));` - this prints "x?y".

Comment: your observation is true, but i made the mistake. ascii doesnt include high chars at all. try with latin1 and "ş" and youll see using default constructor it produces "s", using other constructor and giving replacementfallback, it produces "?"

Comment: this is because Encoding.GetEncoding("latin1").EncodingFallback.ToString() =>  System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest: Right, other encodings may well use the best fit - just not ASCII :) So in general, if a single-byte encoding *knows* that it's using a single-character replacement fallback then it could potentially optimize; in the general case it can't.

Comment: i think microsoft('s framework team) made a lot of inefficient implementations like this, and made lots of usefull types and members internal like this.

Comment: youre right, even its not unlikely some crazy people make own fallback implementation, they could take this account and optimize for all framework's own fallbacks and do what they are currently doing for another custom fallbacks.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest: While there are occasional places where things are genuinely less efficient than they might be, I suspect that there are subtleties which we haven't grasped yet in this case. There usually are when it comes to Unicode...

Comment: i totally agree but there are sometimes very obvious situations like this make me think that way. its not very often though

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest: How does "it's not very often" fit with your "I think the framework team made a lot of inefficient implementations like this" comment?

Comment: more then i expect from a framework which has 12+ years devolopment period, but there is not full of inefficient implementations though.

Comment: and i think framework should be rewritten with consistent design decisions in all namespaces, and with new integrated language features, especially generics. and all obsolete implementations should be removed.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest: Not only would that be incredibly hard to do in terms of being 100% consistent (think about the size of the API, and therefore how many people are involved in creating and maintaining it), but the removal of the old stuff would break backward compatibility massively. It's great if you want to write green-field code, but Microsoft really doesn't want to break the huge body of existing code.

Comment: they could provide all those new or rewritten thing in a new root namespace other then "System" and with the help of existant code and knowledge it would take shorter then the development period of framework 1.0

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest: But that's not removing anything, which is half of what you proposed... and I don't think the benefit would be worth all the rework. Don't forget that MS is working with limited resources. Personally I'm happy that they're spending more of their effort on features like async methods in C# 5.

Comment: let the c# language team work on next c# version, let framework development team work on rework. up 1 to you for your interest

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the [mono runtime doesn't seem to include that behaviour](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Text/ASCIIEncoding.cs#L69):

```
// Get the number of bytes needed to encode a character buffer.
public override int GetByteCount (char[] chars, int index, int count)
{
    if (chars == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("chars");
    }
    if (index < 0 || index > chars.Length) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("index", _("ArgRange_Array"));
    }
    if (count < 0 || count > (chars.Length - index)) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("count", _("ArgRange_Array"));
    }
    return count;
}

// Convenience wrappers for "GetByteCount".
public override int GetByteCount (String chars)
{
    if (chars == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("chars");
    }
    return chars.Length;
}
```

and further down

```
[CLSCompliantAttribute(false)]
[ComVisible (false)]
public unsafe override int GetByteCount (char *chars, int count)
{
    return count;
}
```

Comment: someone could break their implementation providing a custom fallback. but i prefer this implementation over .net framework because i suspect if any body in whole world wrote a custom fallback and a customfallback for a single byte encoding and a custom fallback for a single byte encoding which produces more then 1 byte for single char

Comment: It seems @Margus just posted a nice tidbit about this

Answer (score 1):

For a  multibyte character encoding like UTF8, this method makes sense, because characters are stored in with 1 - 6 bytes. I imagine, that method also applies for a fixed size encoding like ASCII, where every character is stored with 7 bits. In actual implementation however,  `"aaaaaaaa"` would be 8 bytes, as characters in ASCII are stored in 1 byte (8 bits), so `lenght hack` would work in best case scenario.

> Previous versions of .NET Framework allowed spoofing by ignoring the 8th bit. The current version has been changed so that non-ASCII code points fall back during the decoding of bytes.
>   
> Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I understand your question as : `Does worst case scenario exist for lenght hack?`

```
        Encoding ae = Encoding.GetEncoding(
              "us-ascii",
              new EncoderReplacementFallback("[lol]"),
              new DecoderReplacementFallback("[you broke Me]"));

        Console.WriteLine(ae.GetByteCount("õäöü"));
```

This will return `20` as string `"õäöü"` contains 4 characters, that all are off `"us-ascii"` character set limits ( **U+0000** to **U+007F**.), so after encoder, the text will be `"[lol][lol][lol][lol]"`.

Comment: im aware of that, we are talking about frameworks own fallbacks which is used in %99.999 case i believe